# How to make files accessible to all users on Visual Basic app

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-2012, ms-word

I am attempting to make an instructional app for the call canter that I work at. Part of the code allows users to display information through the use of several files in our directory with drop down combo boxes.

For instance, a small portion of the code is similar to this (I did not save the app and bring it home so I am going off memory):

```
If cboGlossaryTerm.SelectedItem("MSN")Then
   Process.Start("S:\MSN.pdf")
End If
```

I put the pdf files in My Resources and the Word files are added under the Solution folder.
I am using filepaths in the code as well.
(I attempted to save the pdf files in the Solutions folder but the pdf was not compatible.

With me adding the files this way, will users who do not have access to the S drive folder be able to display the files? Also, will the files remain accessible in the program if they are deleted from the S drive? If not, how should I be referencing the files in my project? Do I have to reference the pdf files from My Resources? If so, how do I do that in an If-Then statement similar to the one above?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about operating system folder permissions and not about a conceptual programming issue.

Comment: It isn't off-topic, it's just neophyte.  "Check file permissions" is an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what you have there it doesn't look like the pdfs in the S:\ would be available to anyone who doesn't have the drive mapped on their local machine.

as for if the files are deleted, if they are being loaded from the S:\ then when they are deleted from there the program will not be able to find them to load them.

if the program is being installed on the local machines you might want to look at just including the pdfs in the installer and accessing them through the program files path.